# "==,!=,<> ,is,is not " not working with python string

Tags: python

I want to check the letters other than SOS in a given string

input:- `SOSSOTSAR`
output:- `3 (T,A,R)`

```
s = input()

 c=0 

s=s.replace('SOS','')

for i in range(len(s)):
    if(s[i] != "S"):
        c+=1
    elif(s[i+1] != "O"):
        c+=1
    elif(s[i+2] != "S"):
        c+=1
    i+=3    

print(c/3)
```

Comment: you're out of bounds with your check. and "letters other that SOS" means nothing. SOS is a word, not letters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this in one line with a list comprehension:

```
s = input()
print len([x for x in s if x not in 'SOS'])
```

However, if you want the number of *unique* letters in the word that are not `S` or `O` then you could use:

```
s = input()
print len(set([x for x in s if x not in 'SOS']))
```

e.g. if your word was `SOSOTTAR`, the first method would give 4 (T, T, A, R) while the second would give 3 (T, A, R).

Answer (score 0):

You can count each letter in input `s` like so.

```
sum(1 for c in s if c not in "SO")
```

Or replace all the `S` and `O`from the string and use the the length.

```
len(s.replace("S", "").replace("O", ""))
```

Answer (score 0):

From your example, u counting letters that are not equals to letters "S" and "O".

```
len([i for i in s if not (i == 'S' or i == 'O')])
```